# Local TcpListener - allow access from public network

Tags: c#, tcp

I have to write an application for university using ASP.net. My mobile phone should send GPS data to the server backend using a given API. But my application will only run locally on my PC. But to collect useful data I have to leave my private network and move around. So my mobile phone has to send the data through the internet.

I created a simple test script to test if I can connect to a TcpListener running locally on my PC using the public address of my PC:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sandbox {
    public static class Program {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args) {
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 7891);
            server.Start();
            server.Server.Listen(5);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            Task clientTask = client.ConnectAsync(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("the Ip I got when I ask google, whats my IP?"), 7891));
            Task<TcpClient> serverTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

            await Task.WhenAll(clientTask, serverTask);
            
            Console.WriteLine(serverTask.Result.Client.Connected);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I added a rule to the windows defender firewall to open the port to public networks (Anything not mentioned is set to "Any")

```
Profile: All
Enabled: Yes
Action: Allow
Override: No
Protocol: Tcp
Local Port: 7891
```

But I'm still not able to connect to the listener.

EDIT:

FritzBox PORT forwarding

[image]

Comment: Most likely, your campus network is using a NAT. You need to open a port on your campus' router and tell it to forward to your own machine. Some routers allow this using UPnP, but many have that disabled for security reasons.

Comment: It's running on my private workstation at home. I'm not connected to the uni network.

Comment: Did you open that port in your home network modem?

Comment: Yes checked it again. See edit